# Eigenvectors of unitary matrix orthonormal

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to show that for different eigenvalues the eigenvectors of a unitary matrix $U$ can be chosen orthonormal. Let's start by assuming $Ux=\lambda x$ and $Uy=\beta y$, where $\lambda \neq \beta $. Additionally, we denote the conjugate transpose of $U$ as $U^H$. We know that $(Ux)^{H}(Uy)=x^{H}x$ which is also equal to $(\lambda x)^{H}(\beta y)=(\lambda^{H}\beta) x^{H}y$. From this, we get $x^{H}y(1 - \lambda^{H}\beta)=0.$ If we show that $\lambda^{H}\beta \neq 1$, then $x^{H}y = 0$ and the vectors are orthogonal.

I am able to show $\lambda^{H}\beta \neq 1$ in several steps:

1. Write $x^{H}y = (\cos\theta_{1} - i\sin\theta_{1})(\cos\theta_{2} + i\sin\theta_{2})$ and use trig identities to simplify to $\cos(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1}) + i\sin(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})$.
2. Rewrite this as $e^{(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})i}$ and notice that this can only equal $1$ if $\theta_{2}-\theta_{1}=0$.
3. Conclude that this means that the eigenvalues should be equal, which negates our assumption of different eigenvalues.

This seems to do the trick, but it feels somewhat tedious, particularly the trig functions part. Is there a quicker way to notice $\lambda^{H}\beta \neq 1$?

Comment: What about $I_2$? $x=[1,0]$, $y=[0,1]$, $\lambda=\beta=1$. Why would $\lambda\neq \beta$? The eigenspaces of $U$ are orthogonal, so it suffices to normalize the eigenvectors, I'd say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to notice is that, since $U^HU=I$,
$$
x^Hx=(Ux)^HUx=(\lambda x)^H\lambda x=\lambda^H\lambda\,x^Hx=|\lambda|^2\,x^Hx.
$$
So $|\lambda|^2=1$.

Now, if you have $\lambda^H\beta=1$, you multiply the equality by $\lambda$ to get $\beta=\lambda$.

---

By the way, $\lambda^H$ is the conjugate of $\lambda$, and it is universally denoted by $\overline\lambda$.

Comment: Great, this is precisely what I've been looking for. All the trig stuff goes out the window. Thanks!